# Error when updating custom namespace on .resx generation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, namespaces

I am importing some custom code I found on GIT to a project, but am having a problem with VS picking up the namespace changes I am making.

The classes I am importing use a .resx filen (again I have copied these across from the GIT project and included int he project) for language customization and are used as a filter as below;

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
[Display(Name = "Username", ResourceType = typeof(Properties.Common))]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

now if I right click my project the default namespace is set to for example MyCustomNamespace, if I then look at the Common.Desginer.cs (under properties), the namespace is MyCustomNamespace.Properties (I have done a ctrl + shift + h to change all the old namespaces though). However when compiling i get the following error;

> Type or namespace 'Properties' could not be found

Now, if I ammend the attribute to be;

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
[Display(Name = "Username", ResourceType = typeof(MyCustomNamespace.Properties.Common))]
public string Username { get; set; }
```

it finds the Properties.Common, however, if i then have;

```
using MyCustomNamespace;
```

at the top, with the original attribute, it again fails to find the class.

Also, interestingly, my Model is in the namespace;

```
namespace Models.InputModels
```

If I ammend this to be

```
namespace MyCustomNamespace.Models.InputModels
```

then the class is also found?

I assume it down to the copying across of the .resx files and classes across, but I must have missed something? Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: open resx with editor and replace namespace as well?

Comment: yeah, i did this and cant see any reference to the namespace? I also did right-click -> propeties on the .resx file and changed the 'Custom Tool Namespace' option to be MyCustomNamespace.Properties (i have removed since its now blank.)

Comment: try let VS regenerate it(by add one more resource file for example)?

Comment: yes, this is my next port of call, i just updated the question with another bit of info I noticed, just before I try this, does this give any more info?